# Solve not working when doing cross-product

Tags: equation-solving, cross

I am having trouble using Solve function with equations evolving vector cross product. For example if I perform cross product of two vectors:

```
x = {1, 0, 0};
y = {0, 1, 0};
z=Cross[x, y]
```

gives {0,0,1} as expected.

However, if I know x and z, but try to find y for example using Solve:

```
x = {1, 0, 0};
z = {0, 0, 1};
Solve[z == Cross[x, y], y]
```

I get no answer {}

Is there a way to do this in Mathematica?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
Solve[z == Cross[x, y], y \[Element] FullRegion[3]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Well, I don't know what you mean by "doesn't work". It produces a solution for me. If it's the form that you don't like, then @cvgmt provided a similar solution with a slightly different semantic.

Answer (score 5):

```
x = {1, 0, 0};
z = {0, 0, 1};
Reduce[z == Cross[x, y], y ∈ Vectors[3]]
```

[image]

```
Clear[x, y, z, y1, y2, y3, sol];
x = {1, 0, 0};
z = {0, 0, 1};
y = {y1, y2, y3};
sol = ToRules[Reduce[{z == Cross[x, y]}]]
y /. sol
z == Cross[x, y] /. sol
```

[image: > True.]

All of `{y1, 1, 0}` satifies `z==Cross[x,y}` when `y=={y1, 1, 0}`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I am not sure about this. The answer should be y = {0, 1, 0}

Comment: Well, no, @user90441. {0,1,0} is only one specific solution. There is an infinite number of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at this is to convert the equations a cross b == c to the matrix form A.b == c and show that the matrix A is not invertible:

```
(* cross product of vectors a and b *)
aCrossb = Cross[{ax, ay, az}, {bx, by, bz}]

(*{-az by+ay bz,az bx-ax bz,-ay bx+ax by}*)

(* construct equations *)
eqs = Thread[aCrossb == {cx, cy, cz}]

(*{-az by+ay bz\[Equal]cx,az bx-ax bz\[Equal]cy,-ay bx+ax \
by\[Equal]cz}*)

(* matrix form of equations *)
{c, A} = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eqs, {bx, by, bz}]

(*{{-cx,-cy,-cz},{{0,-az,ay},{az,0,-ax},{-ay,ax,0}}}*)

(*A.b reconstructs cross product*)
(*so A.b==c is the system to be solved for b*)
A . {bx, by, bz}

(*{-az by+ay bz,az bx-ax bz,-ay bx+ax by}*)

(*we need to invert A*)

(*but the determinant of of A is zero*)
Det[A]

(*0*)
```